# Can I play an FLV on the iPad Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ipad, flv, flvplayback

I am trying to create a simple app for the iPad that with play an FLV when you click a button.  I am using the code from http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/index.html#VIDEO-USE_THE_MEDIA_PLAYER_FRAMEWORK_FOR_VIDEO_PLAYBACK as a reference.  Here is the code for my click event

```
-(IBAction) btnPlayVideoClick:(id) sender { 
 NSString* videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myVideo" ofType:@"flv"];    

 MPMoviePlayerController* myMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoPath]];
 myMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;


 // Register for the playback finished notification.

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
            selector: @selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
              object:myMovie];
 [myMovie play];

}


-(void)myMovieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*)aNotification 
{
    MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie=[aNotification object]; 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                                  object:theMovie]; 

    // Release the movie instance created in playMovieAtURL
    [theMovie release]; 
}
```

I am able to successfully compile and run the app, but when I click the button the app just exits with no error message or any activity at all.  Is there something that I am doing wrong, or is there some reason I cannot play an FLV using the simulator.  I can't test on a real device yet because I am waiting for approval to get my dev license.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOS devices do not have Flash, so you can't play any Flash video.

Comment: I switched the flv for a sample quicktime video at http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1425 with the same result.  I chose both the sample video that was encoded for the iPod and the one encoded for iTunes.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

iOS doesn't have the correct codecs to play an FLV.  It needs to be reencoded as a .mp4 or .mov file.  Something that iOS can actually play.  I haven't tried to read your code to see if it's valid.. this is just the first thing I notice as being "incorrect".

Comment: Apparently you can Jailbreak to get Flash on there:
http://goodereader.com/blog/tablet-slates/you-can-now-legally-hack-your-ipad/

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you already addressed the Flash issue the next issue I see is that you don't seem to be putting the player view anywhere. You either need to put the view somewhere in your hierarchy or set myPlayer.fullscreen = TRUE;
Without knowing more about your views I can't give you advice on embedding it but check out this bit of sample code from Apple to see how they do it:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1