# Play flv videos in iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, flv

Are there any video players for web development to play FLV file in iOS browser? I know that it is impossible to view FLV in Safari, but maybe there is a plugin which somehow converts it using JS or jQuery, so it is possible to view it in Safari?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I play an FLV on the iPad Simulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345601/can-i-play-an-flv-on-the-ipad-simulator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to play FLV videos in iOS Safari with or without plugin - as there's no flash in it - JavaScript can't do the magic here and process the video directly on the device. (Not yet!)

The only way I can see it done that server would have to convert FLV to iOS friendly format such as MP4 / WEBM and then send the converted video to the device.

Comment: Exactly this. Convert to MP4. Especially since both formats are "containers" and anyways the FLV might contain H.264 video and AAC/MP3 audio just like what Safari expects but the information is arranged differently than usual MP4 so it never plays.